# How do I extract rows from a data frame by identifying a character string in a single column?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, extract

I have a data frame from TCGAbiolinks and need to narrow it down to just unnormalized data. I tried writing some sort of for loop that will return the rows where the tags variable in subset.gbmexp includes "unnormalized" but can't seem to get the code right. Something along the lines of:

```
for (x in subset.gbmexp){
   if (grep("unnormalized", x)){
    data.frame(x)
  }
}
```

Here is subset.gbmexp:

```
> dput(head(subset.gbmexp))
structure(list(file_state = c("submitted", "submitted", "submitted", 
"submitted", "submitted", "submitted"), updated_datetime = c("2017-03-04T20:47:52.066809-06:00", 
"2017-03-05T09:28:11.866514-06:00", "2017-03-05T18:29:39.863030-06:00", 
"2017-03-05T09:28:11.866514-06:00", "2017-03-05T12:32:21.948139-06:00", 
"2017-03-05T11:18:26.999142-06:00"), state = c("live", "live", 
"live", "live", "live", "live"), data_category = c("Gene expression", 
"Gene expression", "Gene expression", "Gene expression", "Gene expression", 
"Gene expression"), version = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
    file_size = c(1513300L, 1518638L, 1518861L, 436273L, 436814L, 
    1500084L), data_release = c("0.0 - 25.0", "0.0 - 25.0", "0.0 - 25.0", 
    "0.0 - 25.0", "0.0 - 25.0", "0.0 - 25.0"), submitter_id = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), access = c("open", "open", "open", "open", 
    "open", "open"), data_format = c("TXT", "TXT", "TXT", "TXT", 
    "TXT", "TXT"), id = c("c76037b3-200b-42ea-a935-7e27b94609be", 
    "81491634-6923-4e5e-adb3-0b05170dafaf", "8ac630d3-3b35-44f9-9076-ab2edfdb33c1", 
    "954c898a-b5ae-4fec-880b-890d4a9e037b", "5cd0729b-3a3a-4de0-8014-038966f5616b", 
    "99077392-c937-4814-9a39-02787ad04ed9"), data_type = c("Gene expression quantification", 
    "Gene expression quantification", "Gene expression quantification", 
    "Gene expression quantification", "Gene expression quantification", 
    "Gene expression quantification"), type = c("file", "file", 
    "file", "file", "file", "file"), cases = c("TCGA-06-0184-01A-01R-1849-01", 
    "TCGA-06-0649-01B-01R-1849-01", "TCGA-02-2485-01A-01R-1849-01", 
    "TCGA-28-1753-01A-01R-1850-01", "TCGA-06-0680-11A-32R-A36H-07", 
    "TCGA-26-5136-01B-01R-1850-01"), file_id = c("c76037b3-200b-42ea-a935-7e27b94609be", 
    "81491634-6923-4e5e-adb3-0b05170dafaf", "8ac630d3-3b35-44f9-9076-ab2edfdb33c1", 
    "954c898a-b5ae-4fec-880b-890d4a9e037b", "5cd0729b-3a3a-4de0-8014-038966f5616b", 
    "99077392-c937-4814-9a39-02787ad04ed9"), experimental_strategy = c("RNA-Seq", 
    "RNA-Seq", "RNA-Seq", "RNA-Seq", "RNA-Seq", "RNA-Seq"), md5sum = c("446a53abb4957c031d98c5c5d8b0d389", 
    "7856260846fba1d83842bf6c28856eaf", "8e8f5d50fa60195f3c5d1c4b6986e232", 
    "a1379ab262859850649051b2df076fec", "f3cd6c2c8616ac3d89e07d5281eddc49", 
    "5c8a99cb4bbbd83b3bb24f49b5f5cb23"), tags = list(c("unnormalized", 
    "gene", "v2"), c("unnormalized", "gene", "v2"), c("unnormalized", 
    "gene", "v2"), c("normalized", "gene", "v2"), c("gene", "normalized", 
    "v2"), c("unnormalized", "gene", "v2")), platform = c("Illumina HiSeq", 
    "Illumina HiSeq", "Illumina HiSeq", "Illumina HiSeq", "Illumina HiSeq", 
    "Illumina HiSeq"), state_comment = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), file_name = c("unc.edu.7522ddf3-0d35-4085-9f94-1ca2e38aa804.1541218.rsem.genes.results", 
    "unc.edu.acb1160e-036a-4108-a9ce-d5f954191593.1538764.rsem.genes.results", 
    "unc.edu.102a0737-7d27-46b8-a433-4f1bb5300858.1545049.rsem.genes.results", 
    "unc.edu.23b23702-8e0f-4b4c-ad92-ce7ea44939e6.1544065.rsem.genes.normalized_results", 
    "unc.edu.94f66829-3cef-4af2-9f97-2352ac85efee.2403684.rsem.genes.normalized_results", 
    "unc.edu.39b5a7b5-e2ec-442d-94c4-ba938ee79b97.1542432.rsem.genes.results"
    ), project = c("TCGA-GBM", "TCGA-GBM", "TCGA-GBM", "TCGA-GBM", 
    "TCGA-GBM", "TCGA-GBM"), center_id = c("ee7a85b3-8177-5d60-a10c-51180eb9009c", 
    "ee7a85b3-8177-5d60-a10c-51180eb9009c", "ee7a85b3-8177-5d60-a10c-51180eb9009c", 
    "ee7a85b3-8177-5d60-a10c-51180eb9009c", "ee7a85b3-8177-5d60-a10c-51180eb9009c", 
    "ee7a85b3-8177-5d60-a10c-51180eb9009c"), center_center_type = c("CGCC", 
    "CGCC", "CGCC", "CGCC", "CGCC", "CGCC"), center_code = c("07", 
    "07", "07", "07", "07", "07"), center_name = c("University of North Carolina", 
    "University of North Carolina", "University of North Carolina", 
    "University of North Carolina", "University of North Carolina", 
    "University of North Carolina"), center_namespace = c("unc.edu", 
    "unc.edu", "unc.edu", "unc.edu", "unc.edu", "unc.edu"), center_short_name = c("UNC", 
    "UNC", "UNC", "UNC", "UNC", "UNC"), sample_type = c("Primary Tumor", 
    "Primary Tumor", "Primary Tumor", "Primary Tumor", "Solid Tissue Normal", 
    "Primary Tumor"), is_ffpe = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE), cases.submitter_id = c("TCGA-06-0184", "TCGA-06-0649", 
    "TCGA-02-2485", "TCGA-28-1753", "TCGA-06-0680", "TCGA-26-5136"
    ), sample.submitter_id = c("TCGA-06-0184-01A", "TCGA-06-0649-01B", 
    "TCGA-02-2485-01A", "TCGA-28-1753-01A", "TCGA-06-0680-11A", 
    "TCGA-26-5136-01B")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, this will only return the value in the first column of each selected row, where I want to build a data.frame including the entire row for each "unnormalized" value. Can anybody explain how I need to rewrite this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you include an example of your data? You can use `dput(data)` or perhaps `dput(head(data))`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Matt this is what I used to get the data: 


`query.gbmexp <- GDCquery(project = "TCGA-GBM",
                  data.category = "Gene expression",
                  data.type = "Gene expression quantification",
                  legacy = TRUE,
                  access = "open",
                  experimental.strategy = "RNA-Seq")

subset.gbmexp <- query.gbmexp[[1]][[1]]`

Comment: Don't put the `dput(head(subset.gbmexp))` results in a comment, edit your question and add it to the box where your code is. If `subset.gbmexp` is a data frame, what column/variable contains the string "unnormalized"?

Comment: It is in the tags column @dcarlson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to select rows 1, 2, 3 and 6, which contain the character string "unnormalized" in the tags column, you could do:

```
subset.gbmexp[grep("unnormalized", subset.gbmexp$tags),]
```